# Is there an elegant way to find the maximum value in a complex 2D array, returning the actual complex value, not just its magnitude?

Tags: python, numpy, complex-numbers

`max(some2Ddata,key=np.abs)` works, but only for 1D complex arrays

`np.max(abs(some2Ddata))` returns the magnitude of the max complex value, but not the value itself

I'm expecting:

```
some2Ddata = ((1+2j, 5+1j), (4+4j, 2+3j))

complexmax(some2Data)
```

Which should return `4+4j`, not `5.657` (and definitely not `5+1j`).

I find it hard to believe that there is not a standard built-in for this operation.

Answer (score 5):

We can write a simple function for this. We can use `np.argmax` to get the index of the maximum value (which will be based on `np.abs`). Because `np.argmax` returns the flattened index, we then use `np.unravel_index` (as per the [`np.argmax` documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) examples) to get the 2D index. Finally, we use that index on the original array.

```py
import numpy as np

def complex_max(a):
    raveled_index = np.argmax(np.abs(a))
    unraveled_index = np.unravel_index(raveled_index, a.shape)
    return a[unraveled_index]

some2Ddata = np.array([[1+2j, 5+1j], [4+4j, 2+3j]])
res = complex_max(some2Ddata)
print(res)  # (4+4j)
```

Comment: Thank You!  I will add that function to my growing library of "functions that ought to be standard".  Although I'm not sold on the elegant part ;-)

Comment: @greg If this answers your question then you can accept it by clicking the check next to it.